# Prevent Mathematica from uncapitalizing letters (specifically for letter I)

Tags: graphics, formatting

I need to use I/I0 to label my y-axis to denote intensity ratio, yet Mathematica converts both I-s to imaginary symbols(small letter I).

I tried using Holdform[I/I0] but it does not work.

Also, I want to prevent Mathematica from automatically creating a fraction when printing labels in the output. e.g. a/b becomes a fraction when I want to print a linear form a/b.

Comment: Try using strings, `"I/I0"`, `"a/b"`.

Comment: Use a string (e.g., "I/I0") rather than symbols. For fractions: `rationalStr[r_] := 
 ToString@Numerator[r] <> "/" <> ToString@Denominator[r]` then `rationalStr[3/4]` evaluates to "3/4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complicated labels (with expressions, formulae etc.) I used to use `Row` like this:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {Row[{a, "/", b}], Row[{InputForm[I], "/", 
Subscript[InputForm[I], 0]}]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 16]]
```

The output plot:

[image]

The point is that if label contains variable (physical quantity, as intensity in your case) it should be in italic. Text goes as usual in roman (upright). Mathematica print labels in TraditionalForm (itallic for single variables, upright for function names). To stop converting special letters like I, E to special representation by mathematica one can use `InputForm`. It is also useful to wrap variable in `HoldForm` to prevent substitution numerical value: if you have definition `a=1` then to use `a` in label you hold it: `Row[{HoldForm@a,"/",b}]`.

Comment: Could you explain how the @ operator works? I am new to programming so I have trouble understanding this.

Comment: @YingXiangTow, thanks for accepting answer. `@` is prefix form of operator (function): `HoldForm@a` is the same as `HoldForm[a]`, it is used for shortening as well as postfix notation `expression//Simplify`.